# Custom view like listview with connecting lines between parent and child

Tags: android

I am trying to make a custom listview with connecting lines like below:

**Parent View**
          |
          |----Child View
          |
          |----Child View
                |
          |----Child View

Not able to draw connecting lines to child views.

Comment: Just try to Create a custom layout for this.

Comment: My first thought is the same to create custom layout. Can you please tell me how do I create a custom layout for the same.

Comment: Can you post a image for this because i am little bit confused with the dashed lines.

Comment: these are not dashed line, these are continous lines, as i can post image (as per policy stackoverflow, as of me :)). For these continous lines, can you suggest me something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this layout file as your ListView Row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/HorizontalLine"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView android:text="Your Text Here"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/HorizontalLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

then set ListView divider drawable to transparent color and listView divider heightto 0dp.
```

Comment: This can help to trigger new idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a divider. The divider can be a image containing this line.
Also if you are looking for a listview which has further child, you can use the ExpandableListview.

Comment: My main concern is to draw lines like shown in question.